# How can I display User Input to another page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

How can I display user input if I have this example.
 (Default.aspx)

 FirstName: (textbox)

 Last Name: (textbox)

I wanted to display the user input coming from Default.aspx to another page (WebForm1.aspx)
using Response.Redirect.

How can I do this ?

Is

```
Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx?VariableName" + TextBox1.Text)
and TextBox1.Text.Request.QueryString("VariableName")
```

working ?

Comment: why are you asking instead of trying?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will work but you need to add `=` after your variable name  as below

```
 Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx?VariableName1=" + TextBox1.Text + "&VariableName2="+ TextBox2.Text);
```

and also in your`WebForm1.aspx`

```
TextBox1.Text = Request.QueryString["VariableName"];
TextBox2.Text = Request.QueryString["VariableName2"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Page one:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String strTxt1 = TextBox1.Text.ToString();    
    String strTxt2 = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
    Response.Redirect("~/new_name.aspx?fName=" + strTxt1 + "&lName=" + strTxt2);
}
```

Page two:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["fName"].ToString();
    Label2.Text = Request.QueryString["lName"].ToString();
}
```